# Anyone knows the full text engine name for postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, bitnami, osqa

I have a AWS ec2 instance running Bitnami OSQA stack(using postgresql), to implement the full text search, I have tried on my develop server(original OSQA with mysql).

The problem is, when I add mysqlfulltext in disable session in Settings_local.py, I can success in my develop server, while in production server AWS EC2 doesn't work, I know there should be some engine for postgresql, but don't know the name.

Anyone know this?

--add
in the part of OSQA settings_local.py, there is a session  as below DISABLED_MODULES = ['books', 'recaptcha', 'project_badges','mysqlfulltext'],it works fine in my developserver with mysql, but for product develop server in postgresql, I tries to use pgsqlfulltext instead but failed for searching.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fulltext engine", but [PostgreSQL supports fulltext by default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-intro.html)

Comment: in the part of OSQA settings_local.py, there is a session  as below DISABLED_MODULES = ['books', 'recaptcha', 'project_badges','mysqlfulltext'],it works fine in my developserver with mysql, but for product develop server in postgresql, I tries to use pgsqlfulltext instead but failed for searching.

Comment: Oh you are asking about the name of OSQA module to enable in order to leverage the fulltext feature of PostgreSQL. Sorry, I have no clue about OSQA ;)

Comment: Correct, so waiting for anyone know it.

Comment: I found [this Q&A](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/3945/search-broken-running-against-postgresql). It is a bit outdated; but it might prove useful.

Comment: Cheers,success finally by pgfulltext instead of mysqlfulltext. Thanks, have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [relevant manual page](http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/OSQA+Installation+and+Upgrade+Guides).

It refers to a module called "pgfulltext".